# How to unzip files in Python?

Tags: python

I am working on a project where if the files in a folder equal exactly 20, the files get zipped up. But if there aren't 20 files then an email is sent instead.

Here is my code:

```py
import zipfile
import shutil
import subprocess
import glob
import os
import time
from subprocess import Popen
# Import smtplib for the actual sending function
import sys
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
import smtplib
import ssl


port = 587  # For starttls
smtp_server = "SMTP.office365.com"
sender_email = "XXX.com"
receiver_email = "XXX.com"
password = 'XXX'
message = """\
Subject: Hi there

there are no 20 files in XXX
"""

context = ssl.create_default_context()
Location = 'XXX'
checklist = glob.glob(Location + '*.zip')

    for files in os.walk(Location):
        if files == 20:
              for filename in checklist:
                  zf = zipfile.ZipFile(filename, 'r')
                  NewName = filename.replace(Location, '')
                  NewName = NewName.replace('.ZIP', '')
                  zf.extractall(Location + "Unzipped\\")
                  os.rename(Location + 'Unzipped\\ZSNP_M36_Q0006_00000.xls', Location + 'Unzipped\\' + NewName + '.xls')

    p = Popen("Macro_SSC_csv_conversion_batch.bat", cwd=r"XXX")
    stdout, stderr = p.communicate()
    print(p.returncode)
        else:
              with smtplib.SMTP(smtp_server, port) as server:
                   server.ehlo()  # Can be omitted
                   server.starttls(context=context)
                   server.ehlo()  # Can be omitted
                   server.login(sender_email, password)
                   server.sendmail(sender_email, receiver_email, message)
```

I can't get the unzipping function to work, can someone help me?

Thank you

Comment: Are all the files in the same folder, or are they in sub-directories?

Comment: Did you know what is return by `os.walk`? Now look at your line under it, `file == 20`.

Comment: or even `os.listdir(path)` or probably `glob.glob(pattern)` that targets specific files/patterns

Comment: all the files are in the same folder yes @Ofer Sadan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the function `os.walk` does not return just a list of files, but even if it did, checking if there are 20 of them is done by `len(files) == 20` and not `files == 20`. You said in your comment that all the files are in the same folder (without sub-directories), so that can easily be done with `os.listdir`:

```
files = os.listdir(Location)
if len(files) == 20:
    do_something()
```

You have some other problems here, like looping over the files and the `checklist` which I'm not sure is intentional, plus some indentation problems, but that is the answer to your question here.